# Displaying hierarchical data from database in unordered list via Repeater control

Tags: asp.net

I have a database table with some Id, parentId and other data-related fields.
I want to display all this in nested `<ul>`s (n-levels of nesting) using repeater control.
(I don't want to use any other 3-rd party controls and also no treeviews...)

First, i read the data (once) from database into a collection (`List<myObject>`) on which I would like to manipulate to get the hierarchical structure.

The problem is how to build repeater's template?
Repeater's template is static, so the only thing that i can prepare is the starting and ending `<ul>` and `</ul>`.

How to be with nested uls? how to create them?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest more repeater controls into the item template, and bind them to a subset of your data.

Alternately, I would suggest programatically building your item template.

Comment: How can i programatically build the item template?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this with a standard repeater. You could nest repeaters, but that'd take some programatic tweaking to build your hierarchy. An alternative would be to use the TreeView control. If you don't like the built-in TreeView and you want cleaner markup, Asp.Net MVC sounds like it'd be a better fit. If you want a more middle-ground solution, Asp.Net's [CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/) may work for better you.

Comment: YES,nested repeater was my initial solution! but i wanted something simpler!

Comment: Simpler to program or simpler result to the client? Binding to a treeview is pretty simple.

Comment: i don't want tree, i am building something more complicated.

Comment: One way or another this is conceptionally a tree. The question is how it emits html--which is why I suggested CSS Friendly Control Adapters. With that, you can have the tree emit a <ul> at the start of each node and have it emit </ul> at the end of each node. "Both a TreeView and a Menu visualize hierarchical information. Without adapters both use HTML <table> tags. Control adapters can be used so that nested <ul> tags are rendered instead."

Comment: I can't use treeview control because every item requires a complex template and treeview doesn't support item templates.